# Eclipse not create a location(string) object. Why?

Tags: android, object, location

I want to calculate distance between two point by google map. i searched and i think that i use of Location object but when i write this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Runnable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.lang.Object;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.location.Location;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;
```

Eclipse writes The android.location.Location; conflicts with a type defined in the same file. and when i create a location object Eclipse writes The constructor Location(string) is undefined.

```
Location location=new Location("");
```

What is the problem? What should i do?
Cheers

Comment: Please edit your post and include the imports statements from the top of your activity.

Answer (score 2):

The conflict may be caused because you may have defined your own Location class or are referring to another Location class defined by some other part of your project (maybe an external library).

Resolve these reference issues by using a fully qualified name. For example, if you have your own Location class then refer to it as `com.mysampleapp.Location` instead of just `Location`.

The constructor is not being recognized because it is referring to the other Location class in your project not the one provide by Google i.e. `android.location.Location`.

This will go away once you resolve the reference issue I just discussed.

Comment: I don't understand what you say! Do you mean i import com.mysampleapp.location to my program?

Comment: I mean that you already have another class named "Location" in your project. That is why you are getting these errors. Find out where it is and reference it with it's fully qualified name .

Comment: What is fully qualified name for location class?

Comment: Meaning the package name followed by the class name. Seems like you need to learn  bit about packages in Java. Here's a good tutorial:
http://www.jarticles.com/package/package_eng.html

Answer (score 0):

For this type of situation Google have made a great service for exactly what you want. Use [Google Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) for this situation. You can use also Google Map API but i think Direction API will be more convenient for your requirement.

For Example If you want to calculate distance between from Toronto, Ontario to Montreal, Quebec. You should query like below:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false

The above query gives you JSON response. And When you put this URL to your browser and you can see the distance between both locations Like :

```
"legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "542 km",
                  "value" : 542397
```

You can use this query in android using HttpClient Class like Below :

```
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(this.URL);
             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(this.postParameters));
             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
             is = entity.getContent();
```

And can get JSON response. You can change `origin=''&destination='' As per your requirement.

Hope it may helpful to you. Please Accept and vote up if you find my answer helpful to you. Enjoy Coding...

Comment: Thanks.But i want to use a location object for calculate distance not other thing!!

Comment: with location class you have to struggle more to achieve above thing. Can you clear what you want actual ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I tried to import

```
import android.location.Location;
```

in the file named Location.java.

A renaming file helps.